# kaspersky internet security blocks requests from my laravel api

Tags: reactjs, laravel, kaspersky

I've designed an application where the front end is in react js and the back end in laravel.the application works fine on browsers but on a browser running kaspersky internet security I get an error 499. Kaspersky considers my back end as a phishing application, which is not the case. What can I do? Thanks

I'd like you to help me find a solution

Comment: Is this in production or local environment? Do you have SSL enabled?

Comment: [False detections by Kaspersky products. What to do?](https://support.kaspersky.com/common/error/other/1870)